# scid vs pc interface

Tags: software, scid

I am having an issue setting up scid vs pc. I see tons of tutorials and they all show a nice interface with the board, analysis, and other windows all visible on one view. However all I get get is the board showing and the current few moves. Everything else is on separate tabs. I have searched high and low through the menus and options and Google  searches but no answers.  I tried to upload the screenshot urls but only one will post, if I ad the second one it deletes the 1st one.  Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It would help us help you if you could post an actual question.

Comment: The implication is that he wants "the board, analysis, and other windows all visible on one view."

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Options -> Windows -> Dock Windows.  If I understand your problem correctly, that may fix it.